# multiple functions in one onClick

Tags: javascript

I want to execute two functions in one onclick,

below my code:

```
<Script>

function checkSubmit(){

if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?');)
    sendData();
}

</Script>
```

The button:

```
<input type="submit" id="send_data"  class="send_data" value="Send" onclick="checkSubmit()"/>
```

It is not executing the sendData() function, any ideas how to execute the two function under one onclick?

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon there after the confirm function?

Answer (score 2):

Format your code better as normally this should work fine

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?')) { // no ; and open the bracket
    sendData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function checkSubmit() { 
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?')) 
        sendData(); 
}

function sendData() { alert("data sent"); }
```